# New install and no ethernet connection

Tags: 16.10, ethernet

My Ubuntu 16.10 is a fresh install. But the Ethernet connection isn't connecting. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue when I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 . The problem was that file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` was not created, so my wired connection did not work. I manually created the file as follows:

```
touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

Afterwards, restart NetworkManager:

```
service NetworkManager restart
```